# Reduce FPS of embedded video & loop iterations at specified timecode

Tags: video, youtube-api

I'm embedding a youtube video which autoplays, and plays only a specified portion of the video (the first time)

Is there any way to make it play slowly, at approximately 1/8th of its normal speed?

And also, continue to play only the specified portion when it loops rather than looping to the beginning of the video?

```
<object width="1000" height="780">
    <param name="movie" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" />
    <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/removedvideoid?autoplay=1&loop=1&start=14&end=18&playlist=removedvideoid" width="1000" height="780"></embed>
</object>
```

I'm not opposed to using an alternate method leveraging HTML5 or JavaScript if it proves to be a better solution but backwards compatibility is an important factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, since I am not sure if there is a parameter for making a video play at a slower rate.

I just wanted to divert your attention to the fact that you are using the old YouTube API.

The new one is called YouTube IFrame API, so you can search for the documentation on Google.

Here is a usage example:

```
<body onload="LoadYouTubeIframeAPI()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var player = null;
        var playerParams =
        {
            playerVars:
            {
                "enablejsapi":1,
                "origin":document.domain,
                "rel":0
            },
            events:
            {
                "onReady":onPlayerReady,
                "onError":onPlayerError,
                "onStateChange":onPlayerStateChange
            }
        };
        function LoadYouTubeIframeAPI()
        {
            var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
            scriptElement.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptElement = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            firstScriptElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement,firstScriptElement);
        }
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
        {
            player = new YT.Player("player",playerParams);
        }
        function onPlayerReady(event)
        {
            player.loadVideoById("your-video-id");
        }
        function onPlayerError(event)
        {
            ...
        }
        function onPlayerStateChange(event)
        {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Search for the documentation of `playerVars`, there might be an option for frame-rate in there...